# Can the width field in a BMP with BITMAPINFOHEADER be negative?

Tags: file-format, bmp

I recently found out BMP images can have negative height, meaning the pixels are stored top-to-bottom in the file. Our production code rejected a file from a user, as it interpreted the height as 4294966272 ( unsigned 32 bit value ) , while the it really was -1024 ( signed 32 bit value ) , actually meaning a height of 1024 pixels. The most "official" documentation of BITMAPINFOHEADER format I managed to find is on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format), which says the width is also a `signed integer`. How would one correctly validate a BMP input?

Answer (score 0):

Since the BMP format [has been used in Windows since version 2.0](http://apps.nationalarchives.gov.uk/pronom/fmt/115) I would use MSDN as the most "official" documentation. In MSDN we find the following [definition of BITMAPINFOHEADER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183376(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
typedef struct tagBITMAPINFOHEADER {
  DWORD biSize;
  LONG  biWidth;
  LONG  biHeight;
  WORD  biPlanes;
  WORD  biBitCount;
  DWORD biCompression;
  DWORD biSizeImage;
  LONG  biXPelsPerMeter;
  LONG  biYPelsPerMeter;
  DWORD biClrUsed;
  DWORD biClrImportant;
} BITMAPINFOHEADER, *PBITMAPINFOHEADER;
```

As you can see, biHeight is defined as long, which is usually the same as signed int. If your code is not reading this value properly, I would say that there is a bug there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Change from unsigned 32bit to signed 32bit 
That should fix it